# Can two usernames be identical?

Tags: discussion, users, duplicate-accounts

See the below image. It would seem that this is the same user.. but when you select one profile, it shows he asked that one question, and when you select another profile, it shows the other question. In other words, it appears these are two different users. Is this valid? Also, when you change your avatar, I'm assuming it changes everywhere (including old questions) correct?

[image]

As for the duplicated question, I have already flagged it for mod attention. I could not flag it as duplicate since the other question did not have an answer yet. Hopefully that was the correct way to handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usernames are not required to be unique, no. I could name myself *Mark P.* too, there are no restrictions on using a username, provided you are not actively trying to impersonate another user.

The avatar shown in the usercard is the avatar for that account; if the account changes their avatar it changes everywhere.

All this means there are two separate accounts involved here; they'll have a different userid each (check in the URL). It could be that it is the same person that created both accounts; it could even be by accident. If you suspect it is the same person, flag one such post for moderator attention, pick *Other* and briefly explain (linking to the other account) and they can investigate if anything needs to be done about this.

Comment: Ok good to know... but two low rep users with the same name in the same the asking the same question within days of each other... seems strange. Like perhaps the initial user accidentally created their account again or something.

Comment: @MarkP.: or they created an *unregistered* account and lost their browser cookie, or they forgot their username and password for the first account, etc.

Comment: I guess to follow up here then, should I bother asking about something like this in the future.. or is it typically not something to worry about?

Comment: @MarkP.: it is hard to say what is going on in this specific case; I'd just flag it for the moderators to investigate.

Comment: Thanks. I just flagged the question earlier for moderator attention, but because I thought it was a duplicate.. not necessarily because of the user situation. Good to know in the future.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that new usernames like "Jon Skeet" were not allowed because of the likelihood of it being an impersonation.  Is this true?

Comment: @MarkP.: In this case, neither account is brand new. The XML in the posts is *subtly* different, but similar enough that I'd flag this for moderator attention as well.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: if you use the name *Jon Skeet* and start trolling about, your account won't last long. If you use that name with a different avatar, different *About me* and contribute helpful content to the site, then the other Jon Skeet will just have to put up with someone that just happens to have the same name.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: e.g. the name Jon Skeet doesn't have to be unique, but so far anyone using it was doing so as a joke (ha ha, laugh).

Comment: These have now been flagged for moderator attention for both the accounts and for the seemingly duplicated questions. Thanks!

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, I remember the recent "Brad Larson".  And that was before I learned who Brad Larson was so I didn't understand the impersonation.  And I saw how that ended.